# UWP FTP Server for RPi2

Tags: c++, ftp, uwp

I'm writing a small, lightweight FTP server for RPi2 running Win10 IoT Core and I get to the point where I'm working on file management but I've run into serious problem. You can't access all files directly without declaring them in manifest or without user interface (pickup box). Is there any way to access all locations without prompting user to select them first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there isn't.

The only locations you can access without asking the user every time, are the libraries (`Photos`, `Music`, `Videos`, etc.), as well as the provided local space for the app itself.

Everything else is protected by the **sandbox** and is only accessable by asking the user for each access.